# Why does renaming `set` break Tcl's interactive mode?

Tags: tcl

Why does renaming `set` break Tcl's interactive mode?

```
info script {}
set tcl_interactive 1
puts [st toupper foo]; # FOO
rename set xyz
puts [st toupper foo]; # Runtime error
```

(See [Ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/IrsIep).)

This question is purely abstract—I noticed this odd behavior while code-golfing and wanted to understand the internals a little better.

---

Er, same thing happens when I rename `regsub`, but not `join` or `split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Tcl is in interactive mode, it stores the commands you type in a history. This is implemented by the [`history`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/history.htm) command, with entries being placed in the history with the `history add` subcommand. (There's a few other things going on too; the default [`unknown`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/unknown.htm) command handler calls in to get things like the previous history entry. But they're only tangential to your question.)

The `history` command is written in Tcl. It's [implementation](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/4d5a635c327fa29e) apparently uses `set` (among other things) inside the implementation of the `history add` subcommand, but not `join` or `split`. The `unknown` command is *also* conventionally written in Tcl (I don't have such a nice link; it's buried in `init.tcl`). It uses more commands, including `regsub` (but only in complex history parsing).

In general, some parts of Tcl are written in Tcl because writing everything in C would suck to maintain. If you unwisely overwrite or remove parts of Tcl, things will break. You're free to break them if you want, but then you do get to keep the pieces. (If you're replacing a standard command and expect to be still running standard scripts, you'd better duplicate its functionality with the original name pretty closely or breakages will happen. *Caveat scriptor*.)

Comment: The problem here is not `history`, it's `unknown`. Unknown calls `set` (does not exist) -> calls `unknown`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn But `history` also calls `set`, and every command typed in interactively goes through `Tcl_RecordAndEval` which these days just does a `history add` call. The loop in `unknown` happens after that…